# Embedded JavaScript for-loop explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to use a for-loop in EJS to render my table, but I keep getting this error saying it can't find my variable:

```
TypeError: /Users/martin/Documents/Atom-files/Nye_eksempler/testApp/public/views/billing.html:41
   39| <% for (var i = 0; services.length; i++) { %>
   40| <tr>
>> 41| <td><%= services[i].name %></td>
   42| <td class="alignright"><%= services[i].price %></td>
   43| </tr>
   44| <% } %>

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The problematic code is this:

```
<% for (var i = 0; services.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= services[i].name %></td>
    <td class="alignright"><%= services[i].price %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

and the way the view is being rendered is this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.render('billing.html', {
    total_payment: '$43',
    name: 'martin scorsese',
    date: '25. may',
    billing_id: '#213123',
    services: [{name: 'flight', price: '$22'}, {name: 'car', price: '$21'}]

  } );
});
```

Why is this giving me an error? My other variables load without problems, it's just the for-loop and the 'services'-variable that's causing trouble.

Comment: your index is out of bounds ... for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error on defining the for loop: you forget to define the upper limit of the iteration. In your case the index is out of bounds.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= services[i].name %></td>
      <td class="alignright"><%= services[i].price %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```